# Which is the best way to store different versions of the file which is of the form HashMap and the User can ask for any Version?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a file of the form HashMap<Property, Value>. For this file, there is an update in one/all of the field for each version. I wanted to know what is the best way to store this type of file s as to have best runtime with efficient space utilisation ?

Comment: Please provide an example of an update operation.

Comment: it will be an update in one of the fields. for example : 
The Map can be of the form HashMap<String, String> properties = Map.of("key1","value1", "key2", "value2");
now update operation is properties.put("key1","value3") -> this will be second version of the map. and user can ask any version.